# Wrapping Promises to do something when consuming, resolved and rejected: differences with chaining?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'd like to make a function what "wrap" `Promise` and:

1. Do something when the promise is invoked **(1)**
2. Do something when the promise is resolved, but retain original value **(2)**
3. Do something when the promise is rejected but retain the error **(3)**

I'm not very confident with promises... here is what I may do:

```js
const wrap = (promiseToWrap) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('loading...'); // (1)
    
    promiseToWrap
      .then(res => {
        console.log('show success toast'); // (2)
        resolve(res);
      })
        .catch(err => {
        console.log('show error toast') // (3)
        reject(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Assuming this solution is right, what's the difference with chaining a new `Promise` (the one that do "something") with the passed `promiseToWrap`?

Comment: Wrapping a promise in a promise constructor is an anti pattern. I don't see, why you would do it in your case. I would remove the wrapping promise and `return promiseToWrap.then...`.

Comment: The "loading" message is useless. In general, the promise that is passed as argument could be in any state. It could have been created 10 minutes ago, it could already have been resolved, ... So "loading" what? Also, promises are not "invoked". They are objects, not functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new promise, you can chain the existing one. To keep the return value and error, just `return` the value and re-throw it respectively:

```
const wrap = promiseToWrap => {
  console.log('loading...'); // (1)
    
  return promiseToWrap.then(
    res => {
      console.log('show success toast'); // (2)
      return res;
    },
    err => {
      console.log('show error toast') // (3)
      throw err;
    }
  );
}
```

Better though, write it with `async`:

```
const wrap = async (promiseToWrap) => {
  console.log('loading...'); // (1)
  
  try {
    const res = await promiseToWrap;
    console.log('show success toast'); // (2)
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('show error toast') // (3)
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply "latch onto" the promise to trigger additional callbacks, and return the original promise unchanged:

```
const wrap = promiseToWrap => {
  console.log('loading...'); // (1)
    
  promiseToWrap.then(
    res => console.log('show success toast'), // (2)
    err => console.log('show error toast') // (3)
  );

  return promiseToWrap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm wrong for sure, but "comsuning a promise" is when one call .then right? So the function would immediatly consume promiseToWrap? What I'm missing?

Comment: `.then` doesn't "consume" a promise. It *adds a callback which will be called when the promise is in a fulfilled state.* You can even add `.then`s to already fulfilled and "consumed" promises as many times as you want.

Comment: @gremo also Promises don't "wait" for you to call .then, as soon as they're constructed they are working on whatever it is they're constructed to do.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is equivalent to

```
const wrap = (promiseToWrap) => {
  console.log('loading...'); // (1)
  return promiseToWrap
      .then(res => {
        console.log('show success toast'); // (2)
        return res;
      })
        .catch(err => {
        console.log('show error toast') // (3)
        throw err;
      });
}
```

or more succinctly

```
const wrap = async (promiseToWrap) => {
  console.log('loading...'); // (1)
  try {
    const result = await promiseToWrap;
    console.log('show success toast'); // (2)
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('show error toast') // (3)
    throw err;
  }
};
```

This probably isn't what you want.

Note that Promise callbacks are immediately invoked, by the time the Promise to wrap is passed to your function it is already "loading" and may well be resolved.